# PHP jQuery "unterminated string literal" error in onclick handler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using PHP to pass variables into the `onclick` of an element, however when I do this I get an "Unterminated string literal" error of the string is too long. My PHP is as follows:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name, Image, Description, Link, Price, ID FROM gallery ORDER BY ID desc");

            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($name, $img, $desc, $link, $price, $id);

            while($query->fetch())
            {
                if(strlen($desc) > 100)
                {
                    $sdesc = substr($desc, 0, 100) . '...';
                }

                $onclick = 'popup(\'' . $name . '\', \'' . $desc . '\', \'' . $price . '\', \'' . $img . '\', \'' . $link . '\', ' . $id . ')';

                echo '<div class="gallery" onclick="' . $onclick . '">
                    <img src="' . $img . '" alt="' . $name . '" />
                    <div><p>' . $sdesc . '</p>
                    <a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank">' . $price . '</a>
                    </div></div>';
            }
```

My jQuery is as follows

```
function popup(title, desc, price, img, link, id)
            {
                $(".popupbodyg").children().remove();

                var HTML = '<input type="image" src="close.gif" id="close" /><div><div id="comments">' +
                            '<iframe src="comments.php?id=' + id + '"></iframe><br /><input type="image" id="share" src="Very-Basic-share-icon.png" /></div>' +
                            '<div id="desc"><p>' + desc + '</p><br />' + 
                            '<a class="gallery" href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + price + '</a></div>' + 
                            '<div id="img"><img src="' + img + '" alt="' + title + '"/></div></div>';

                $(".popupbodyg").append(HTML);
                $("#popup").toggle();

                $(".popupbodyg #img").css("width", $(".popupbodyg").width() - 230 + "px");
                $(".popupbodyg #img").css("height", $(".popupbodyg").height() - ($("#desc").height - 5) + "px");

                $("#close").click(function(){
                    $("#popup").hide();
                });

                $("#share").click(function(){

                    $("#sharepopup").show();

                    $("#sharepopup").find("#link").attr("value", "http://www.encantojewellerydesign.com/gallery/?g=" + id);
                    $("#sharepopup").find(".fb-share-button").attr("data-href", "http://www.encantojewellerydesign.com/gallery/?g=" + id);

                    $("#sclose").click(function(){
                        $("#sharepopup").hide();
                    });

                });
            }
```

The only way I can think of right now is by limiting the amount of characters in the description, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Use `"` on the outside and `'` on the inside in your PHP strings so you don't have to use `\'` or `\"` all the time.

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?  (PHP?  what line number? - javascript?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try any of the string replace methods that are found elsewhere on SO?

```
$desc=str_replace("\n","\\n",$desc); //I'm guessing that the newline would probably be in the description if anywhere in the data you're passing.
```

ALSO:
Another slightly different approach would be to just embed the data into your element and retrieve the data with a single click handler that passes it to your popup function.

In other word, you could change the div.gallery look like this:

```
<div class="gallery" data-name=".$name." data-img=".$img." data-desc=".$desc." data-link=".$link." data-price=".$price." data-id=".$id.">
```

Then add an click handler like this:

```
$('gallery').on('click', function() {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  var img = $(this).data('img');
  var desc = $(this).data('desc');
  var link = $(this).data('link');
  var price = $(this).data('price');
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  popup(title, desc, price, img, link, id);
});
```

Comment: I'll try both the solutions!

Comment: Well, I decided to do the second oen first, and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming that it has to do with the extra html characters that $description and other variables are passing to yout js. Try may be something like this(for a better answer, post a dump of the variables you are passing):

```
<?php
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name, Image, Description, Link, Price, ID FROM gallery ORDER BY ID desc");

            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($name, $img, $desc, $link, $price, $id);

            while($query->fetch())
            {
                if(strlen($desc) > 100)
                {
                    $sdesc = substr($desc, 0, 100) . '...';
                }

                $onclick = 'popup(\'' .strip_everything( $name ). '\', \'' . strip_everything($desc ). '\', \'' .strip_everything $price) . '\', \'' . $img . '\', \'' . $link . '\', ' . $id . ')';

                echo '<div class="gallery" onclick="' . $onclick . '">
                    <img src="' . $img . '" alt="' . $name . '" />
                    <div><p>' . $sdesc . '</p>
                    <a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank">' . $price . '</a>
                    </div></div>';
            }

            function strip_everything($str){
                $str = strip_tags($str);
                return str_replace("\n" , ' ' , $str);
            }
```

Comment: There isn't any HTML at all in these strings

Comment: Not yet, no, I'll try it now.